# Combo box is auto filling with option, How to get it to be Null

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2007

I have never had this problem before, but when I make a form and insert a combo box normally it will be empty until I enter my data, however on this one occasion one of the options is showing up in the combo box and I have no idea how to stop this so when I add a new entry there is no data in the combo box, unless I choose or type my answer.

Please help it is driving my insane as like i said before this has never happened, and I did every thing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check combobox's property DefaultValue. If combobox is bound, also check default value of its' data source field.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the property's where all the same as usual.. However I did find the problem, it was because I set the ID for one of the options as 0 which I have never done before.